# Estimating the uncertainty of a bias and a scatter

Tags: statistical-significance, standard-deviation, outliers, bias, measurement-error

I have one single set of observational data. Assuming I know the right answer for one property of this data set and then I use one tool to measure this quantity. To get an estimate of the amount of the error in the measurement, I evaluate the **bias**, **scatter** and **number of outliers** using this tool to measure this specific property of data, because I want to use this result to obtain statistical sense from the performance of this tool on the other data set where I don't have access to the right answer.

**My Question**: How can I find the uncertainty in the measurement of these quantities (bias, scatter and outliers) too, when I just have one single available observation and I want to just use this sample to get errors of the bias and scatter and so on.. quantities too?

BTW, my definition of bias is the median of this quantity
 $$\Delta M=M_{obser}-M_{measure}$$

Scatter is the standard deviation of the distribution of $\Delta M$ and the outlier is when $|\Delta M|>\alpha$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the phrase "one single available observation" mean a single *number* or a single *set of numbers* (corresponding to your "single set of observational data")?

Comment: @whuber It means a single number of observational data.

Comment: That's just as confusing as before!  Are you talking about *one number* or *multiple numbers*?

Comment: @whuber I am talking about one single number not a set.

Comment: It baffles me how you could hope that a single number could tell you anything about any of these quantities (bias, scatter, and outliers), all of which are related to how much *multiple* numbers vary.  What did you have in mind?

Comment: @whuber well I have done other couple of tests but then for this particular test I want to know if the difference between bias or scatter for different tools are different just by for instance `0.002`, what does it tell me? Is it just a statistical error or one of them has more systematic error than the other?

Comment: @whuber is there anything called as `an error of errors`? Does it make sense to resample a single observation? I am not sure my argument is correct or not! I need an expert opinion.

Comment: It makes no sense at all to me, because to "resample" a single observation would change nothing.

Comment: @whuber I tested two tools for measurement of one quantity and the difference between them is very trivial, how could I conclude which one is better or is there any other statistical quantity that I can measure and make decision based on it?

Comment: @whuber I am reading statistical literature about bias and scatter and I came across some diagnostic test called **funnel plot**. Are you familiar with this plot? I don't know whether it might be helpful to make this plot or even is it plausible to use it in my case?

Comment: @whuber If I do bootstrap the observational data and compute the quantity that I am looking for to measure. Then it does mean that I can get errors on **bias** and **scatter**. Is it right to do so?

Comment: We are completely failing to communicate. You have repeatedly made it clear that you have a *single number*. Nothing that you mention makes any sense for a single number, so there is nothing I can think of to give you a meaningful reply.

Comment: @whuber Can you suggest a diagnostic test if I want to compare two tools for a measurement of a quantity?

Comment: I believe you might find some useful advice, or at least pointers worth following, by looking at the posts that turn up in a site search for [calibration chemometrics](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=calibration+chemometrics).

Comment: @whuber could you please narrow down the subject or tests? The literatures and topic are so broaden.